# Apply Combo Discount to a Food Order

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

An app lets users order food from a menu. The menu has three types of selection: main, drink and dessert. A feature needs to be added which will discount the price by 10% for every main+drink combo (10% off every combo). All items ordered by the customer are stored in an array like so:

```
order = [
{id: 4, count: 1, type: "main", price: 10}
{id: 5, count: 2, type: "drink", price: 9.5}
]
```

As you can see, each item the customer orders has a count property. How can I apply the discount without mutating the order array or any of the object properties? Ideally I'd like to loop through the array, determine total number of combos (in the example above it would be 1), determine the total discount value and pass that value to another function which computes the order total. If anyone can suggest a better way of doing it, I'm all ears (or eyes in this case).

Also, what is the best way to express this problem from a technical point of view?

Comment: `(order[0]['count']*order[0]['price']) + (order[1]['count']*order[1]['price']) - (Math.abs(order[0]['count']-order[1]['count'])*(order[0]['price']+order[0]['price'])*0.1) ` The part after the first minus sign is the discount if I understand your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const userOrder = [
  { id: 4, count: 1, type: "main", price: 200 },
  { id: 5, count: 1, type: "drink", price: 100 }
];

const orderInfo = userOrder.reduce((acc, cur) => {
console.log('cur', cur)

  if (acc[cur.type]) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [cur.type]: cur.count,
      totalAmount: (cur.count * acc.totalAmount) 
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [cur.type]: cur.count,
      totalAmount: (cur.count * cur.price ) + acc.totalAmount
    }
  }
}, {
  main: 0,
  drink: 0,
  totalAmount: 0
});



const noOfComobosPresent = Math.min(orderInfo.main, orderInfo.drink); 

const totalDiscountValue = noOfComobosPresent * 10; 

const finalAmount = orderInfo.totalAmount - ((orderInfo.totalAmount * totalDiscountValue ) / 100) ; 

console.log('finalAmount', finalAmount)
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. We must multiply the price by the count. The number of combos depends on a drink AND main being present, not one OR the other. Also I'm not sure why you are multiplying the discount value by 10.

Comment: My bad, good catch I missed those considerations, now I have made the changes you can test it in `ts playround`. Regarding the `discount value * 10` I am doing it because for one combo it is 10% and if 2 combos 20% and so on...